# Turn this if-then logic into a boolean expression?

Tags: algorithm, binary, bit-manipulation, boolean-logic

I'm having a bit of a brain fart on making this code more concise(preferably a single boolean expression)

This is my code:

```
                    if (d.Unemployed)
                    {
                        if (type.Unemployed)
                        {
                            tmp.Unemployed = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tmp.Unemployed = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (type.Unemployed)
                        {
                            tmp.Unemployed = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tmp.Unemployed = true;
                        }
                    }
```

Basically the point is that if either `type` or `d` is not unemployed, then `tmp` should be set to not unemployed.

Comment: Do you mean “`type` or `d` is not unemployed, *but not both* ”?

Comment: @svick: Yes, that's confirmed by the if-else logic in the code.

Comment: @Justin, that's why I asked. Your code says something else than your text, or at least it's not clear they mean the same thing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about:

```
tmp.Unemployed = type.Unemployed == d.Unemployed;
```

Comment: Ah, now it's obvious that I think about it. Just needed another pair of eyes I guess

Answer (score 8):

If we construct a truth table by following the code, we get

```
d  | type | tmp
---+------+----
1  |   1  |  1
---+------+----
1  |   0  |  0
----+-----+----
0  |   1  |  0
----+-----+----
0  |   0  |  1
```

The above is equivalent with the negation of the `xor` operation.

```
tmp = not (d xor type)
```

If the language doesn't have the `xor` operator we can use the `!=` on boolean values.

```
tmp = ! (d != type);
// or
tmp = d == type;
```

Answer (score 2):

Thinking about how much "brain fart" this caused you I would consider using a well named variable to avoid having to go through this mental process again in future. Something like this:

```
isTmpUnemployed = (type.Unemployed == d.Unemployed);
tmp.Unemployed = isTmpUnemployed;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp.Unemployed = d.Unemployed || type.Unemployed ? !tmp.Unemployed : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code means "both unemployed or both not unemployed".  Thus, not (A xor B):

```
 tmp.Unemployed = ! ( D.Unemployed ^ type.Unemployed)
```