# ansible playbook if else if

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements

I have a few output variables. Around 4 different types of error conditions are possible and a single successful condition, which I check using `when` condition. But it is more of an if else if else if else condition. I don't want to even check the second, third and fourth condition if first condition becomes true and skip to final summary task.

How to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ansible is a Configuration Management Tool](https://www.ansible.com/use-cases/configuration-management) with which you [declare a state](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html), ideally [idempotent](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-Idempotency).

> and a single successful condition, which I check using when condition.

Since there is one correct state, one would define that state in playbook only. There is no need for checks then.

Appart from that, with [Conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html)

> [, if you have multiple conditions, you can group them with parentheses.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts)

> [You can use logical operators to combine conditions.](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#logic)

To achieve your goal you should have a look into [turn ... if then logic into a boolean expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657494/turn-this-if-then-logic-into-a-boolean-expression/6657518).

Furthermore, there are a lot **Q&A** here on SO which answered your question already.

- [Ansible `if` `else` construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42037814/)
- [`If` `else` syntax in Ansible playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62898165/)
- [`If` `else` in Ansible print statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54428075/)
- [Ansible `if` `else` condition based on gathered fact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57435109/)